# can we pass parameters to appsec.yml hook ApplicationStart phase?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-code-deploy

I want to deploy my application to aws, I am using codeDeploy for this.
following is my appsec.yml file:

```
version: 0.0
os: linux
files:
  - source: /
    destination: /home/ubuntu/project
permissions:
  - object: /home/ubuntu/project
    owner: root
    mode: 777
    type:
      - directory
hooks:
  BeforeInstall:
    - location: scripts/install_dependencies.sh
      timeout: 900
      runas: root
  AfterInstall:
    - location: ./scripts/after-install.sh
      timeout: 900
  ApplicationStart:
    - location: ./scripts/application-start.sh parameter1 parameter2 
      timeout: 900
  ValidateService:
    - location: ./scripts/validate-service.sh
      timeout: 900
```

I am not able to pass paramerters to scripts.

Answer (score 1):

Currently this is not possible.

As a workaround, you can design your Hook Scripts to consume System Environment Variables which can be defined on a instance at launch (through user-data) or you can also retrieve the parameters from AWS SSM Parameter Store (specially if they are secrets) using AWS CLI:

- https://docs.aws.amazon.com/systems-manager/latest/userguide/sysman-paramstore-cli.html

Answer (score 0):

You can create an if clause using the predefined environment variables. Based on the situation you configure the required values [predefined environment variables](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/devops/using-codedeploy-environment-variables/)